# Google Analytics: share data between multiple accounts?

Tags: google-analytics, user-tracking

currently we have a company blog that runs via blog.domain.com. Also we have our corporate site (domain.com) that is our "selling" site. The blog is about tutorials, open source stuff, totally non profit.

We want to examine if the blog has value to our business. Branding and so on... Will customers visit our blog, are users from our blog more likely to buy sth and so on.

Both Domains are within the same Google Analytics Account but as separate properties. Is it somehow possible?

I dont want to use something with Referal as solution since it just might be that someone visits our blog and returns after some week via an ad.

Answer (score 0):

You cant analyse Google Analytics data across properties or accounts.   Data can only be analyzed within the same property.

This is why its best not to split data between properties but to store everything in the same property when its the same web account.   At the very least having one default property with all of the data can also be useful.

Comment: Alright, if I merge the properties then: How would I do my analysis? With "Segments"? I'd like to create a group of users that have visited the blog subdomain. But the Options done give me anything with the uri. or at least i can't find it